# "BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally." - but backup job continues

Tags: sql-server

I have a scheduled backup job that backups a list of several databases.

If there is a problem backing up a database, the log file terminates with the message, `"BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally."` but the rest of the databases are still backed up.

**Is there some way to get the logging to continue?**

Comment: There should be more descriptive messages before this final message, containing error and/or message numbers.

Comment: yeah, I know why the backup of the database failed, but if the backup job continues doing the rest of the databases, it's a problem not having the logging continue